# how to access elements of an arrays in an array in dart flutter?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, command

I am trying to create an flutter app that takes command from speech and then according to specific command, it will print specific text. For this, I have created a class **Command** that have an array of **commands** that further contain 3 arrays as follow:

```
class Command {
  static final commands = [
    activity,
    face,
    object,
  ];

  static const activity = ['activity,is person using, giving, taking, waving'],
      face = ['standing, which teacher, looking, coming'],
      object = ['where is, is there'];
}
```

The issue is that I do not know how to access the activity, face and object array. The error occurs in this line:

> terms: Command.commands,

```
 body: SingleChildScrollView(
          reverse: true,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0).copyWith(bottom: 140),
            child: SubstringHighlight(
              text: textSample,
              terms: Command.commands,
              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.teal,
                fontSize: 30,
              ),
              textStyleHighlight: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          )),
```

I have tried other methods also but got error.

> terms: Command.commands[],

Kindly tell me how can I access complete arrays within an array to be matched to show results.

Comment: did u try `Command.commands[0]` to access activity and `Command.commands[0][0]` to access the first item in activity?

Comment: Why don't you directly access them as Command.activity, Command.face and Command.object ? Or is there something else you're trying to do which prevents you from using them as I mentioned ?

Comment: You have not told us exactly what error you're observing. However, note that the type of `activity`, et. al. is `List<String>`, and the type of `commands` is `List<List<String>>`. The `terms` argument of `SubstringHighlight()` requires `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that I do not know how to access the activity, face and
> object array

```
class Command {
  var commands = [
    activity,
    face,
    object,
  ];

  static const activity = [
        'activity,is person using, giving, taking, waving',
        'second value in activity'
      ],
      face = ['standing, which teacher, looking, coming'],
      object = ['where is, is there'];
}
```

To access these data, you have to do this:

```
print(Command().commands);
// Print all value inside commands variable [[activity,is person using, giving, taking, waving], [standing, which teacher, looking, coming], [where is, is there]]

print(Command().commands[0]);
// Print all activity variable: [activity,is person using, giving, taking, waving]

print(Command().commands[0][1]);
// Print value inside activity variable by index, 'second value in activity'
```